# Firefox enable/disable specific addons when switching mode

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, private-browsing

I have some addons for Firefox which I would like to use in normal browsing mode. And There are some other addons which I'd like to use when browsing in incognito (private browsing).

Now is there a way in Firefox to atuomatically activate/deactivate specific addons when entering/leaving a browsing mode?
Thanks.

Comment: While I can't say whenever that's possible you could use different profiles for this case.

Comment: @Seth Thanks for the suggestion, but using profiles -while it may work- seems like a pretty cumbersome and kind of overkill approach. I was looking for something more specific (and possibly easier to use).

Comment: You're actually trying to use profiles, just one level up. From my understanding extensions work on a process level so it would be hard to manipulate extensions into "honoring your settings. Taking [this](https://support.mozilla.org/de/questions/926986) it would seem that extensions do get notified of private browsing so in theory they could act different - if they support it.